# dijit.form.FilteringSelect css

Tags: dojo, dijit.form

I cannot fig. out how to style the text inside of a dijit.form.FilteringSelect dropdown box. Default, the text is black and the background is also, so you can only see the text when you hover (white hover box).

I'd like to change text to white, then onhover black.

here's my html

```
<select dojoType="dijit.form.FilteringSelect" id="mapLayout" name="mapLayout">
    <option value="Landscape8x11" selected="selected">8 1/2 x 11 Landscape</option>
    <option value="Portrait8x11">8 1/2 x 11 Portrait</option>
</select>
```

here's my css (doesn't work)

```
#mapLayout{
    color: #ffffff;
};
```

another try (doesn't work)

```
.claro .dijitTooltipContainer .dijitInputInner{
    color: #ffffff !important;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
.dijitComboBoxMenu .dijitMenuItem {
 color: #FFFFFF;
}

.dijitComboBoxMenu .dijitMenuItemHover {
 color: #000000;
}
```

Comment: perfect! works great! i have yet to fig. out what classes are important when using firebug...

Comment: Any way to do set the CSS based on the value of the menu item in a CSS file?